# How to match two dict entries based on specific field value

Tags: python, networking

So, I wasn’t sure how to go about this efficiently. I know a way to do it but it’s very inefficient.

Here’s the situation. Take the following data structure.

R1.yml

```
   [{‘interface’: ‘g0/0/1’, ‘role’: ‘active’, ‘ha_ip’: ‘192.168.10.1’}, {‘interface’: ‘g0/0/2’, ‘role’: ‘standby’, ‘ha_ip’: ‘192.168.20.1’}]
```

R2.yml

```
   [{‘interface’: ‘g0/0/1’, ‘role’: ‘standby’, ‘ha_ip’: ‘192.168.10.1’}, {‘interface’: ‘g0/0/2’, ‘role’: ‘active’, ‘ha_ip’: ‘192.168.20.1’}]
```

So what I want to do is be able to identify the host pair based on a hostname (in the yml filename, which I know how to do) and identify identical HA (high availability) IPs. Also need to know which is active and which is standby to know the sequence to apply the configurations to the devices.

Doing nested for loops could work but if I have 50+ of these files it could become time consuming.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Turn the lists into dictionaries that use the IP as the keys.

Comment: So take those then do something like r1dict.keys() & r2dict.keys() to return a set and then work from there? I'm not seeing the endgame

Comment: Loop through one of the dicts, and then look up `r2dict[r1dict[currentIP]].role`